# How to handle sqlalchemy UnpicklingError?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

My database started to throw an error while getting table rows using `sqlalchemy` (Flask application):

[image]

The only column in my model that uses pickling is `images`:

```py
images = Column(PickleType, nullable=True)
```

I don't know how my table turns out to have these bad data in this column and I need to clean them. It's okay to loose these values, I don't really need them all. I have a list with broken rows identifiers, so I can run query - but, still, I can't change the data. And I can't understand what am I doing wrong.

[image]

The value `b'\x80\x04]\x94.'` is simply square brackets. No rows changed after this query - the same error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include code samples and error messages as text, not images. See [ask] for more information on how to improve your question.

Comment: Have you changed your Python version?

Comment: @ilja-everilä I don't think so.